# Different controllers for (almost) the same route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two routes that are almost identical:

```
.state('route', {
        url: '/route/:id
```

and

```
.state('newroute', {
        url: '/route/new
```

The first one takes in a parameter, id, and the second one is a static route. They each have a different controller but I can't seem to figure out how to get the /route/new to take affect, it keeps routing me to the first state's controller with "new" as the id.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the second route before the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the `/route/new` route before the one with the ID, then ui-router will pick it up with priority

Comment: Bingo, that did the trick. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!